# Installing EPSON GT-S80 Workforce scanner & printer drivers

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, epson

I'm not Ubuntu/Linux saavy at all.. can someone please give me specific well-articulated instructions on how to download and install the drivers for the abovementioned scanner/printer/fax unit?

Comment: did you try if it is working ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a printer, but scanner.

For scanner driver go to [Epson drivers site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)

Search for your model, and download drivers.

You will need

```
 esci-interpreter-gt-s80_0.2.1-1_amd64.deb
 iscan-plugin-esdip_1.0.0-5_amd64.deb
 iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
 iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb
```

if your system is 64-bit.

Copy these files to your home folder and run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install *.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thanks very much.. We'll try it and get back to you shortly

Comment: everything worked perfectly - thanks so much :)

Comment: @KirkworxDupuis Why not accept the answer then? Click the "bird" at the left.